# What does message means in UML sequence diagrams?

Tags: uml

In UML sequence diagrams, given two objects A and B, if `Object A` sends a `message` to `Object B`. Does this mean the `message` is a method in `Object B` which is invoked from `Object A`?

Answer (score 5):

UML diagrams are an abstraction. What a message is exactly can be different depending on what concrete entities your diagram shows. The lifelines are not necessarily objects, and the diagram might also be at a higher level of abstraction where a message represents something more complex.

Another factor is that the original concept of "object oriented programming" actually used the [concept of messages](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Dynamic_dispatch/message_passing), not methods - methods are merely a limited (but efficient) way to implement message handlers.

So **if** the lifelines in your diagrams represent objects in a language that uses only methods to implement message handles, and if the person who draws the program wants it to show low-level concepts **then** your UML messages will represent method calls.

Answer (score 3):

Sending a message from Object A to Object B is any form of communication initiated by Object A. One of possible forms is calling a method of Object B. But it can be also a signal captured by Object B or even something more complex/totally different. Since UML is not restricted to programming only it can even be one person (Object A) telling something the other person (Object B).